# SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'CompanyID' property" PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, xml-parsing

Here is the common Soap error what we are facing in our project while sending SOAP request..

Please find the PHP code below and sample of SOAP request....

```
        $client = new SoapClient("url for wsdl",
                 array(
                    'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_1, // Default Version
                    'trace'          => true,
                    'exceptions' => true,
                    'style' => SOAP_RPC, 
                    'use' => SOAP_ENCODED
                    )
                 );


                $parimaryName = array(  
                    "Company" => "xyz",
                    "FirstName" => "test",
                    "LastName" => "test",
                    "Mi"=>"test",
                    "NickName" => "t",
                    "Email" => "test@test.com"
                 );

            $customer = array(
                     "CustClassificationID" => 12345,
                     "PrimaryName" => $parimaryName,
                     "EnrollerDistributorID" => 345545
                );


                $webser= array(
                'APIKey' => 'xxx-xxx-xxxx',
                'CompanyID' => xxx,            
                "Customer"=> $customer

                );

                $ccRequest= array(
                    "WebServiceCredentialsBase"=>$webser,
                    "CustomerCreateOnlyRequest"=>$req                       
                );    

                $final=  array( 'Request' =>  $ccRequest);

                try {

                $result = $client->myServiceCall($final);
                echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); echo "</pre>";
                echo "Success"."<br />";
                echo("\n<p><pre>Dumping request:\n" . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) . '</pre></p>');
                echo("\n<p><pre>Dumping response:\n" . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse()) . '</pre></p>');              
              } catch(Exception $e) {
                echo "Failure"."<br />";
                echo("\n<p><pre>Dumping request:\n" . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) . '</pre></p>');
                echo("\n<p><pre>Dumping response:\n" . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse()) . '</pre></p>');
                echo "Caught Exception"; echo "</br>";
                var_dump($e->getMessage());
            }
```

Error :-

```
Caught Exception
string(56) "SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'CompanyID' property"
```

I tried to debug error but no solution !!

Please guide me where I am doing mistake !!

Thanks !!

Comment: Seems like `'CompanyID' => my id,` is not filled

Comment: @Fabio 'CompanyID' => 123 //// I have added API key as well as companyid ... please check it..

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense but try to surround with quotes

Comment: If you had compare __getLastRequest with desired soap request packet (Provided by SOap API Service). I mean it is possible to companyId reside at wrong location on SOAP XML packet.

Comment: We tried already...  but not working !!

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj Even I am thinking same.. May be we are sending companyId inproper or XML request what we are sending is improper...

Comment: @neeraj your not supplying right params to the service. use the getdatatypes method to seem the params structure to be passed.

Comment: @Swapn14 ok..But can you please tell me how to pass as a getdatatype.. I know gettype in php.. Thanks

Comment: Either you start learning about SOAP or I suggest you use something different than SOAP that is not that complicated. Apart form that general advice all I can say is that the question in it's current form *can not be answered*. If you need guidance about the mistake you do, I would say, the first mistake is to not get into the know what that error message actually means. No offence please, you asked that way, so you get a response on the same level.

Comment: You closed the question ok fine... But still I cant understand why this is closed.... @hakre ,Yogesh Suthar, Ocramius, and All... Thanks !!